# How to clone ASP.NET Controls using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html-table, clone

I just want to ask if it is possible to clone an asp control using Javascript because I find it hard to add another row, the same as the row before it..

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteRow(row) {
        var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
    }
    function myFunction()
        {
        var table = document.getElementById("POITable");
        var row = table.insertRow(2);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        cell1.innerHTML = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('#asp:DropDownList')[0];
        cell2.innerHTML = row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('#asp:DropDownList')[0];
        cell3.innerHTML = row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('#asp:TextBox')[0];
        cell4.innerHTML = row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('#asp:TextBox')[0];
        cell5.innerHTML = row.cells[5].getElementsByTagName('#asp:TextBox')[0];
        cell6.innerHTML = row.cells[6].getElementsByTagName('#asp:Label')[0];
        }
        </script>
```

And here is the table wherein I want to clone the row:

```
<div id="POItablediv">
           <table class="table" id="POITable">
           <tr class="th">
               <td>Fabric</td>
               <td>Color</td>
               <td>Good For How Many</td>
               <td>Consumption</td>
               <td>Allowance</td>
               <td>MRP Quantity</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td> <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFab" runat="server" DataSourceID="DSFabric" 
                                DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Description" Width="120px">
                                </asp:DropDownList></td>
                <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColor" runat="server" DataSourceID="ddlColors" 
                                DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Description" Width="120px">
                                </asp:DropDownList></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtGdForHwMany" runat="server" Width="120px" 
                        ontextchanged="txtGdForHwMany_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtConsump" runat="server" Width="120px" 
                        ontextchanged="txtConsump_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtAllow" runat="server" Width="120px" 
                        ontextchanged="txtAllow_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblMRPQuantity" runat="server" Text="0" Width="120px"></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="Add More POIs" onclick="myFunction()"/></td>
           </tr>
           </table>
       </div>
```

The `DropDownList` is databounded.

Answer (score 1):

1. DropDown on the client side will be converted into "< select />" so getElementByTagName will not work for asp:DropDownList. You will have to use like getElementByTagName("select") or if you are using jQuery, then you can give a class name to drop down and have selector for that class name like $(".className") to get the drop down list.
2. similar for < asp:TextBox /> tag will be < input /> or use class name for it
3. for < asp:Label />, tag will be < span /> or use class name for it

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This won't work the way you expect, for a start asp.net renders controls as HTML. That is `asp:dropdownlist` becomes a `<select>...</select>` , `asp:textbox` is `<input type="text/>` etc when rendered to the page .

Further more if you successfully clone the row you will have duplicate `name` and `id` attribute for your form elements.

An additional problem is the new elements wont be exposed to the code behind page as a normal asp.net element would. The would be accessible using the `Request` object, but you still have the problem of duplicated name attribute.

Comment: is there any way that i can add new row in a table where I can inherit the asp controls in my table?